Performance comparison: BufferedInputStream vs. Unbuffered Streams in Java
I created a file with 1,000,000 zeroes in it (980K) and measure how fast to copies it to another file (using buffered and non-buffered for both input and output) with default buffer size (8192 bytes). Surprisingly, buffering both input and output significantly improved performance. this is the result
While I understand that large file reads that exceeding the buffer size (8KB) might negate buffering benefits, I don't understand why the performance from using the buffer is still better than not using one (At least it takes less syscall). The only downside I see here seems to be unnecessary memory usage for the buffer itself.
Question is: 1.Except in memory-constrained environments where memory usage is a concern, why don't we always use buffer for both input and output?

Why is it faster to copy a file when the output is buffered?

My code includes functions like t1(), t2(), t3(), and t4() which I will not share in full here since they are similar to the code provided:
static void t2() {
        System.out.println("Copy file using BufferedInputStream (8192), with BufferOut");
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        try (BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("text.txt"));
             var bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("text_3.txt"))) {
            int i;
            while ((i = br.read()) != -1) {
                bOut.write(i);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;

        System.out.println("Duration: " + duration + " millisecond");
    }

I've tried using in.transferTo with both buffered input&output and the result is even better (1 digit millisecond). I also plan to experiment with different buffer sizes. I read that the optimal size depends on the file system block size, which in my case is 4,096 bytes. Should I set the buffer size to 4,096, or is it the bigger the better?

You are not doing "large file reads" here. In your code, you are reading one byte at a time. That is a lot of reads. Having a buffer essentially means you are reading 8192 bytes at a time, instead of one byte at a time.

Hi @Sweeper,thanks for the info!  So, you're suggesting I read 8192 bytes at a time? But wouldn't that negate the benefit of buffering the input in the first place? I'm quite sure each byte read was from the buffer.

I was not suggesting that you read 8192 bytes at a time. I was saying that without a buffer, you would be reading one byte at a time (i = br.read()). By using a buffer, you read more bytes at a time, and this is why the buffer is faster. Did I misunderstand what you are asking?

@Sweeper the question is 1. Except in memory-constrained environments where memory usage is a concern why don't we always use buffer for both large and small reads as I've seen people saying that BufferedInputStream is good only for bunch of small reads. 2. Why does buffering the output also lead to faster file copying compare to not using it? I appreciate you help here.

@Magaroni: a common example where (unspecific) buffering can be bad is any interactive session: If your shell would buffer all output of any program until e.g. 8k bytes are output before it would output stuff then you wouldn't see much progress by many small tools until they are fully done. In these cases you want to see the output as soon as possible (or buffer at most one line worth of text, for example). Similarly sending requests/responses over the network means that there's usually a very specific boundary when you want to send stuff which isn't pre-measured in bytes.

You're "copying" the file by reading and writing a single byte? For an un-bufferred stream you're making an incredible amount of system calls which is slow.  When the stream is buffered, the buffered stream will reduce the number of system calls. For the file copy, if you read/write larger chunks. The bufferedstream shouldn't change because it is already doing that.

Also, note that you can read from an InputStream to a byte[] and also write a whole byte[] to an OutputStream which is what BufferedInputStream/BufferedOutputStream does.

You are using read(), which reads a single byte at a time. That is slow for reasons already explained. The same is true for write(int). When you use the buffered input/output streams, it means there is a byte[] buffer being used behind the scenes. So, while from your own code it looks like you're still reading and writing a single byte at a time, you are actually reading and writing many more bytes at a time, reducing the number of system calls on both ends. If transferTo is truly faster, I would guess it's because the same buffer is being used for reading and writing.

"Surprisingly, buffering both input and output significantly improved performance." Why surprisingly? The usage of a buffer is exactly to improve the performance

The is the low-level operating system I/O. Even when writing byte wise in java there probably is some non-java memory buffer.
Using non-buffered java I/O will have a lot of calls from java to the OS level that then sporadically transfers a buffer. This is very costly.
Using buffered java I/O is considerably faster copying the java buffer in one single native call to the OS level and then does the actual I/O (assuming same sized buffers).
You are right this takes a bit of memory for the java buffer.
There is a third alternative to buffered and immediate non-buffered I/O.
This uses memory mapped files. This operates straight on the OS level buffer (creates, reads, writes). MappedByteBuffer. Search how to use a FileChannel and ByteBuffer and the code is not really harder to write.
Now it seems you did not mention the great Files class. Using the more general Path instead of File you can do all those I/O easily: newByteChannel.
P.S.
One should mention long InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream) (which can work asynchrone without much blocking between input and output) but then Files.copy exists too. I gather for understanding the underlying mechanism you used the more basic coding.
